# About calling functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

tur = ['alfa', 'sayı', 'diğer']
alfabe = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ç', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'ğ', 'h', 'ı', 'i', 'j', 'k',
 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ö', 'p', 'r', 's', 'ş', 't', 'u', 'ü', 'v', 'y',
 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Ç', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Ğ', 'H', 'I', 'İ', 'J',
 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Ö', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'Ş', 'T', 'U', 'Ü', 'V',
 'Y', 'Z']
sayilar = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
# Klavyeden basılabilecek alfasayısal olmayan karakterler
alfa_sayisal_degil=['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',',
 '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[',
 '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
def alfabe_uret(zınk):
    list=[i for i in alfabe]
    zınk=random.choice(list)
    print(zınk)
def sayi_uret(zınk2):
    Liste = [i for i in sayilar]
    zınk2=random.choice(Liste)
    print(zınk2)
def alfsaydegil_uret():
    pass
    return
def parola_uret():
    pass
    return
print("Size önerebileceğimiz parola :")
print(sayi_uret)
print(alfabe_uret)
```

When I try to run this code I get this output. How can I call those variables in those functions without these different numbers

```
<function sayi_uret at 0x039FFBB8>
<function alfabe_uret at 0x039EAF60>
```

Comment: You print just the representation of the functions themselves. You have to call the functions with apropriate parameters. (In fact, it seems like those parameters are not needed at all, though.)

Comment: Even though I add them () it gives the error: TypeError: sayi_uret() missing 1 required positional argument: 'zınk2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the functions. Just replace

```
print(sayi_uret)
print(alfabe_uret)
```

with

```
print(sayi_uret())
print(alfabe_uret())
```

## EDIT:

You must remove the function arguments as they are unused:

```
def alfabe_uret():
    list=[i for i in alfabe]
    zınk=random.choice(list)
    print(zınk)

def sayi_uret():
    Liste = [i for i in sayilar]
    zınk2=random.choice(Liste)
    print(zınk2)
```

Comment: TypeError: sayi_uret() missing 1 required positional argument: 'zınk2'

Comment: Even though I write my Argument it gives NameError

Answer (score 2):

Replace your last few lines with this:

```
print(sayi_uret())
print(alfabe_uret())
```

Currently the functions aren't being executed.

Comment: TypeError: sayi_uret() missing 1 required positional argument: 'zınk2'

Comment: Give your function any argument, like this: print(sayi_uret(1))
print(alfabe_uret(1))

Comment: NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

here is the fixed code (the functions were defined wrong):

```
import random

tur = ['alfa', 'sayı', 'diğer']
alfabe = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ç', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'ğ', 'h', 'ı', 'i','j', 'k','l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ö', 'p', 'r', 's', 'ş', 't', 'u', 'ü', 'v', 'y','z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Ç', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Ğ', 'H', 'I', 'İ', 'J','K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Ö', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'Ş', 'T', 'U', 'Ü', 'V','Y', 'Z']
sayilar = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
alfa_sayisal_degil=['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',','-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[','\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']

def alfabe_uret():
    list=[i for i in alfabe]
    zınk=random.choice(list)
    return zınk
def sayi_uret():
    Liste = [i for i in sayilar]
    zınk2=random.choice(Liste)
    return zınk2
def alfsaydegil_uret():
    pass
    return
def parola_uret():
    pass
    return

print("Size önerebileceğimiz parola :")
print(sayi_uret())
print(alfabe_uret())
```

Comment: TypeError: sayi_uret() missing 1 required positional argument: 'zınk2'

Comment: @SouSageYa what do you mean?

Comment: When I tried to run (sayi_uret()) and (alfabe_uret()) like this I got that error

Comment: but my answer included a number

Comment: When I put numbers there it gives Name Error

Comment: not just `number`, you should choose a number like `1`

Comment: When I said numbers I meant 1,2,3,4 things like that

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be

```
import random

tur = ['alfa', 'sayı', 'diğer']
alfabe = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ç', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'ğ', 'h', 'ı', 'i', 'j', 'k',
'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ö', 'p', 'r', 's', 'ş', 't', 'u', 'ü', 'v', 'y',
'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Ç', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'Ğ', 'H', 'I', 'İ', 'J',
'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Ö', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'Ş', 'T', 'U', 'Ü', 'V',
'Y', 'Z']
sayilar = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
# Klavyeden basılabilecek alfasayısal olmayan karakterler
alfa_sayisal_degil=['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', 
',',
'-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[',
'\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
def alfabe_uret():
    list=[i for i in alfabe]
    zınk=random.choice(list)
    return (zınk)
def sayi_uret():
    Liste = [i for i in sayilar]
    zınk2=random.choice(Liste)
    return zınk2
def alfsaydegil_uret():
    pass
    return
def parola_uret():
    pass
    return
print("Size önerebileceğimiz parola :")
print(sayi_uret())
print(alfabe_uret())
```

Output

```
Size önerebileceğimiz parola :
3
B
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the last two print statement as:

```
print(sayi_uret())
print(alfabe_uret())
```